# Get records of a table which exists in another table distinct field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**land_information**

```
id  | title_number   | owner      | case_no
1     001              John          201
2     002              Peter         202
3     002              Andrew        203
4     003              Mores         204
```

**sheets**

```
id   | title_number
1      001
2      001
3      002
4      NULL
5      Unavailable
```

Now, I need to check if `title_number` of sheets table exists in land_information.

How should I make a query which will result like the expected result below.

Expected Result

```
id   title_number     owner           case_no
 1      001          John                201
 3      002          Peter, Andrew       202, 203
```

Here is my initial sql.

```
SELECT id, 
       li.title_number, 
       owner 
FROM sheets AS s 
INNER JOIN land_information AS li ON s.title_number = li.title_number;
```

Comment: What's the logic for getting peter in the result for title number = 1? Given that 1 only has john in land_information

Comment: And what is the relevance of `case_no` to the question?

Comment: sorry, I got typo. I edited my expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
MIN(sheets.id) as id, 
sheets.title_number as title_number,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT land_information.owner ORDER BY land_information.id SEPARATOR ',') AS owner,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT land_information.case_no ORDER BY land_information.id SEPARATOR ',') AS case_no
FROM sheets INNER JOIN land_information ON sheets.title_number = land_information.title_number
GROUP BY (sheets.title_number);
```

I'll explain one row at a time:

`MIN(sheets.id) as id,` selects the minimum value from the sheet.id column, inside the group (as it looks inside you expected result)

`sheets.title_number as title_number,` self explains, it just selects the title number

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT land_information.owner ORDER BY land_information.id SEPARATOR ',') AS owner,` groups (enumerates) all land_information.owner, each being added just one time (the `DISTINCT` keyword), separated by a defined separator

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT land_information.case_no ORDER BY land_information.id SEPARATOR ',') AS case_no` same as above, with the `case_no` column

`FROM sheets INNER JOIN land_information ON sheets.title_number = land_information.title_number` here we are inner joining both tables, based on the `title_number` column

`GROUP BY (sheets.title_number)` all rows having the same title number are joined together, and the coresponding functions defined above are applyed on the group.

The result I've got looks like this

```
id|title_number|owner       |case_no|
--+------------+------------+-------+
 1|001         |John        |201    |
 3|002         |Peter,Andrew|202,203|
```